# Test server capacity

Tags: testing, load, traffic

Is it possible to simulate a large amount of traffic to a server, to test how it holds up against all the requests?

The server is not currently live, it will not interfere with continuing service.

Comment: Yes. You may be looking for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_load_testing (there is a list of various testing SW at the bottom; some of it does load testing)

Comment: what type of service? if it's http you probably already have a tool installed on the machine, it's apache httpd's ab (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html). if you need something more complex check apache's jmeter: http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) in the past, though I'm sure there are other tools out there.